# On the login screen everything is fine but when after login pixels are shown on screen

Tags: gnome, keyboard, login-screen

I use ubuntu 20.04 on the login screen everything is fine but when I login then pixelated lines and patters come on the screen. Some keyboard button also stopped working after login. Please help. I think this happened after i installed some codes from ubuntu. I deleted git and everything related to it. But the problem is still there. I have intel uhd 620.

Comment: I also tried to use my android as a second screen for laptop so I installed something from git and then I also used lightdm.

Comment: To see if this is Xorg related, try (temporarily) changing to Wayland: on the log in screen, before entering your password, click the cog wheel and select the Wayland session. In addition, edit your post and add information about your graphics card

Comment: i tried it with wayland the screen problem is gone but some keys stopped working on my additional keyboard.

Comment: Information useful for identifying the error should be in your question. "Some keys"  is not particularly useful information. If you do not stay on Wayland, you could check whether adding the kernel boot parameter ` i915.enable_psr=0`  does not help. I need to use this with an Intel graphics card.

Comment: When I reset my dconf editor everything works fine but when I restart my ubuntu again the problem continues.

Comment: Excellent. However, use ""edit"  to add relevant info to your question. Comments are only aimed at improving a question or answer, and can disappear anytime. Not everybody will read through the comments, moreover.